# How to detect many small red laser dots correctly using CV?

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I am working on a project, which needs to detect many small red laser dots correctly using Opencv. In the end, I want to find all the red laser dots out correctly. Now I changed the rgb to hsv and set the range to detect red dots, then used the canny and findContours function in the opencv to detect the edge and find countours. However, the result isn't very good. some red dots weren't detected well. you could see the picture below. Could you give me some advice about it? [laser lights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8NZF.jpg)

[detection result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGy0c.jpg)

below is my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# set red thresh 
lower_red = np.array([0,0,255])
#156, 100, 40
upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
while(1):
    ret, frame0 = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame0,0)
    frame = frame[50:360,280:380]
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)   
    edged = cv2.Canny(mask, 30, 200)    
    cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))

    # Draw all contours
    # -1 signifies drawing all contours
    # for c in contours:
    #   M = cv2.moments(c)
    #   cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    #   cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    #   cv2.drawContours(frame, c, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    #   cv2.circle(frame,(cX,cY),2,(255,255,255),-1)
    #   cv2.putText(frame,"center",(cX - 20, cY - 20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5,(255,255,255),2)
    cv2.imshow('Capture',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I've recommended NOT using Canny on forum.opencv.org and I'll recommend the same here

Comment: Do you manage to use light source to shine on the object? It will give more contrast on the laser dot for better detection

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to play with the individual channels of your image? you can get better contrast between the laser dots and the background if you use for example the green channel of your image.

```
import cv2 [enter image description here][1]

image = cv2.imread("cv2/images/laser.jpg")
b, g, r = cv2.split(image)
ret, newIm = cv2.threshold(g, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('New Image', newIm)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, I tried your method, the result is good, thank you so much

Comment: @zhizhongPeng You're welcome! Do you mind upvoting my answer? I'm trying to improve my reputation here. Thanks